# BigQuery: flatten the table

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any way that I can simply flatten the below table so that I can multiply (num*num_2) as mul and then later I can sum(mul) group by id.
So really I am looking for table which is similar to second image shown below.

[image: Existing table]

[image: Expected Output]

PS: If I unnest then the result is something like shown below which doesn't help me in what I would like to achieve
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below few options (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, [STRUCT<num INT64, num_2 INT64>(2013, 2013),(1625, 1625),(1297, 1297),(7634, 7634)] nums UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [STRUCT<num INT64, num_2 INT64>(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5)]
)
SELECT id, (SELECT SUM(num * num_2) FROM UNNEST(nums) nums ) as mul
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
```

OR

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, [STRUCT<num INT64, num_2 INT64>(2013, 2013),(1625, 1625),(1297, 1297),(7634, 7634)] nums UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [STRUCT<num INT64, num_2 INT64>(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5)]
)
SELECT id, SUM(num * num_2) AS mul
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`, UNNEST(nums) nums
GROUP BY id
```

both return below

```sql
id  mul  
1   66652959     
2   55
```

If you would not need do SUM(num * num_2) but rather just have flattened your table  - you can use below example

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, [STRUCT<num INT64, num_2 INT64>(2013, 2013),(1625, 1625),(1297, 1297),(7634, 7634)] nums UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [STRUCT<num INT64, num_2 INT64>(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5)]
)
SELECT id, num, num_2
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`, UNNEST(nums) nums
```

Comment: you are awesome. It's working fine with the example. I just need to apply to the real data. Hope it works there too. Thanks a lot for the quick reply

Comment: This one of the example which you have provided to others


WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2013,1625,1297,7634' AS string_col UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '1,2,3,4,5'
)

SELECT id, 
  (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(CAST(num AS INT64)) 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(string_col)) AS num
  ) AS num,
  ARRAY(SELECT CAST(num AS INT64) 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(string_col)) AS num
  ) AS num_2
FROM yourTable'


How can I get this into struct format so that I can easily multiple which you just suggested

Comment: I think, I answered your original question. If you have more question - please post new one as a new question and I will be more than happy to answer it. also please consider voting up answers that helped you :o) thus motivating us to answer your next questions

Comment: in any case  - it is really hard to answer the question that is being asked within the comments - so posting a new question is a good practice here on SO

Comment: Thanks sure, i'll post a new one and kindly help. My new question is simply want to get the array into struct format so that I can multiply as you suggested.

Comment: @Mihail Berlyant. Here is my new question which is an extent to this. Appreciate your help
[Link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272583/bigquery-struct-format